# How can I use SQL to apply a ledger of 'actions' to a given table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I use PostgreSQL 14 to work on a `student_books` table which manages books borrowed by students. Each student can have zero or more books borrowed at any point in time. The table look like this (the order of rows doesn't matter).

| student_id | book_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 113 |
| 2 | 37 |
| 5 | 94 |

Furthermore, I have an (append-only) `library_ledger` table with recent transactions at the library. It keeps track of whether a student borrowed or returned a book, and when. The order of rows matters, it's sorted in ascending order on the first `date` column:

| date | action | student_id | book_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-11-20 09:14:09 | borrow | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-11-21 17:43:22 | return | 1 | 113 |
| 2022-11-22 14:03:04 | borrow | 5 | 204 |
| 2022-11-22 14:03:08 | return | 5 | 94 |
| 2022-11-22 14:03:15 | return | 5 | 204 |

Given the `student_books` and `library_ledger` tables, I'd like to compute the new set of books borrowed by each student. In the above case, I'd like to get the result set

| student_id | book_id |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 37 |

It's not difficult to write e.g. a Java program which processes each row in the `library_ledger` and updates the `student_books` table by issuing `INSERT`/`DELETE` queries. However, I wonder if this can be done in SQL directly.

Maybe if the initial table is grouped by student_id and aggregating the book IDs using `array_agg`, one could use that as the starting value for an aggregate function which processes the actions in `library_ledger` by transforming the array using either `array_append` or `array_remove` (depending on the value in the `action` column). At the end, the result could be un-nested.

Is there maybe a simpler way to achieve this, possibly even without using a custom aggregate function?

Comment: What makes a book 'new' in the 'new set of books'?  Do you want all those cases in student_books table combined with all those from library_ledger where the book is borrowed and not returned? why is student:5 book:94 in both tables but in 'returned' state (in the latter table)?

Comment: @tinazmu The 'new' set of books is the one which we get after applying all transactions in the `library_ledger` to the initial state, given by the `student_books` table. `student:5, book:94` is present in both tables since student 5 is known to have the book, and the ledger shows that she returned it (and thus, the final set no longer contains this row).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're considering an aggregate function here. I think the basic idea is something like:

Remove the records where the most recent `library_ledger` action for that student/book is a "return"...

```
DELETE
FROM student_books
WHERE (student_id, book_id) IN
(
 SELECT student_id, book_id
 FROM
 (
  SELECT student_id, book_id, action, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id, book_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
  FROM library_ledger
 ) sq
 WHERE rn = 1 AND action='return' -- Most recent action is "return"
)
```

... then add in any student/book pairs that don't already exist in `student_books` and have a most recent action of "borrow"

```
INSERT INTO student_books
SELECT student_id, book_id
FROM 
(
 SELECT student_id, book_id, action, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY student_id, book_id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
 FROM library_ledger
) sq
WHERE rn = 1 AND action='borrow' -- Most recent action is "borrow"
AND (student_id, book_id) NOT IN -- Doesn't already exist in table
 (
  SELECT student_id, book_id
  FROM student_books
 )
```

I don't really see any reason to consider intermediate actions, since only the final one (for each student/book pair) should matter.

You can see [my attempt in this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6yocXawR).

Comment: Aaah, good point! Your approach is much simpler, thanks a lot for prodding me in the right direction here. :-)

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of `journal` and `ledger`, there could be a need to understand between borrows and returns for auditing or accounting purpose. For example,

```
select student_id, 
       book_id,
       action,
       date,
       count(action) filter (where action='borrow') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as borrow_count,
       count(action) filter (where action='return') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as return_count
  from library_ledger;
```

Gives us an idea of:

```
student_id|book_id|action|date                   |borrow_count|return_count|
----------+-------+------+-----------------------+------------+------------+
         1|    113|return|2022-11-21 17:43:22.000|           0|           1|
         2|      3|borrow|2022-11-20 09:14:09.000|           1|           0|
         5|     94|return|2022-11-22 14:03:08.000|           0|           1|
         5|    204|borrow|2022-11-22 14:03:04.000|           1|           0|
         5|    204|return|2022-11-22 14:03:15.000|           1|           1|
```

Based on that, the SQL action is determined:

```
with cte as (
select student_id, 
       book_id,
       action,
       date,
       count(action) filter (where action='borrow') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as borrow_count,
       count(action) filter (where action='return') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as return_count
  from library_ledger)
select student_id,
       book_id,
       max(borrow_count) as borrow_count,
       max(return_count) as return_count,
       case 
          when max(borrow_count) > max(return_count) then 'insert'
          when max(borrow_count) < max(return_count) then 'delete'
          else 'noop'
       end as sql_action
  from cte
 group by 1,2;
```

We get:

```
student_id|book_id|borrow_count|return_count|sql_action|
----------+-------+------------+------------+----------+
         1|    113|           0|           1|delete    |
         2|      3|           1|           0|insert    |
         5|     94|           0|           1|delete    |
         5|    204|           1|           1|noop      |
```

For practices like accounting, there could be a review or an approval before apply those actions. After that, update `student_books` (kind of like account balance).

```
-- 1. delete
with cte as (
select student_id, 
       book_id,
       action,
       date,
       count(action) filter (where action='borrow') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as borrow_count,
       count(action) filter (where action='return') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as return_count
  from library_ledger),
cte_delete as (
select student_id,
       book_id
  from cte
 group by 1,2
 having max(borrow_count) < max(return_count))
delete from student_books sb
 using cte_delete d
 where sb.student_id = d.student_id
   and sb.book_id = d.book_id;

select * from student_books;  
  
-- 2. insert
with cte as (
select student_id, 
       book_id,
       action,
       date,
       count(action) filter (where action='borrow') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as borrow_count,
       count(action) filter (where action='return') over (partition by student_id, book_id order by date) as return_count
  from library_ledger),
cte_insert as (
select student_id,
       book_id
  from cte
 group by 1,2
 having max(borrow_count) > max(return_count))
 insert into student_books
 select student_id, book_id
   from cte_insert;
```

```
student_id|book_id|
----------+-------+
         2|     37|
         2|      3|
```